# Why has traffic on my site spiked suddenly?

Tags: discussion, seo, traffic

I've noticed that traffic on my favorite site (and a few others) has spiked recently:

[image]

Why has this happened and is it going to last?

Comment: This hasn't affected my Teletubby fanfic site yet, sadly.

Comment: @Andrew'saUnitato I searched. I saw just the summaries. I demand some brain bleach. It cannot be unseen. I blame you.

Comment: @MichaelT Should I have marked that NSFW?

Answer (score 22):

Google tweaked their search algorithm yesterday:

[image]

(More info [here](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2014/05/21/pandamonium_as_google_updates_key_search_algorithm/) on The Register).

Interestingly it only seems to have affected some sites: and that doesn't include SO:

[image]

> Is it going to last?

Unfortunately there is no way of knowing, but yes, it might - it's not like a burst of traffic you might get from a link on somewhere like reddit that'll be gone in a couple of days.