# Quantcast says it does not directly measure traffic for sites under stackexchange.com domain

Tags: bug, status-completed, statistics, traffic, quantcast

Stack Exchange uses Quantcast, and we get to enjoy directly measured traffic data for [Stack Overflow](https://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com), [Server Fault](https://www.quantcast.com/serverfault.com), and so forth. This used to be the case for all SE sites, [as seen here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/232388/).

But something went wrong with the sites under stackexchange.com domain, such as  [Programmers](https://www.quantcast.com/programmers.stackexchange.com):

[image: quantcast]

(I also tried Cooking and Math; same story)

Not sure if I should already tag this [blame-caching](/questions/tagged/blame-caching)

Comment: Weird - it was fine yesterday, and now it's gone.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks for your patience while we worked this out on our end - we have corrected the issue and you should now be able to view subdomain profiles on Quantcast.com:

https://www.quantcast.com/programmers.stackexchange.com?country=US

Best,

Dave Burke

Quantcast

Comment: Wow, that was the easiest [status-completed] I've had to mark - thanks!